# Xamarin.Forms OAuth/ Facebook SDK login

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Dear Xamarin developers,

I'm new to the Xamarin world and I like Xamarin.Forms.

When a developer find out a new platform (for me Xamarin(.forms)) he/ she wants to let the user login via OAuth (Facebook/ Google/ Twitter).

For Xamarin you have Xamarin.Auth, but I can't get it to work with Facebook or any other provider.

And for Xamarin.Forms there is no library or guide to do this.

So my question is; how do I implement OAuth(2) in Xamarin.Forms to use Facebook as provider?

Thanks in advance,

Theo

Answer (score 0):

I have used Xamarin.Auth to authenticate against Dropbox with OAuth2 following this guide https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/.
As the documentation of the API was not sufficient when it came to error handling, I pulled the branch https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/portable-bait-and-switch from Xamarin.Auth at github to be able to debug it. Later I switched back to the nuget version once I understood the main problems.
For Microsoft Authentification, I had to redefine some of the methods to be able to use it.

Hope this helps to get you started.